# What is required to integrate Grails with Spring Social (Facebook, Twitter and Google)

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-google

My Spring is pretty good (or certainly used to be, its been about 2 years). Grails I'm pretty new to.

I would like to do 2 things.

1. Integrate Spring Security with my Grails application.
2. Integrate Spring Social, Facebook, Twitter and Google to allow social login and signup.

I can see that there are Spring Social Core, Spring Social Facebook and Spring Social Twitter plugins for Grails, though I'm not entirely clear on what they do or why they're needed.
Am I wrong in thinking that Spring Social extends Spring Security? That being the case I would expect a Spring Security integration to handle it.

The Grails plugins also don;t look like they've been modified recently so I'd appreciate it if somebody with experience could clear the fog.

Cheers

Comment: I haven't tried integrating with Spring Social, but I've had success with the *spring-security-oauth* plugins.  I use the core, facebook, google, and twitter versions.  It works well with Spring Security.

Comment: Thanks for the in sight. I'll have a look at the oAuth plugins. Waiting to see what, if any experience others have had with my preferred stack.

Comment: Hi @advis, we've decided to go the same route you tried we've integrated security core and we're now starting on the oAuth.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider looking at the spring social plugins for Grails:

https://github.com/Grails-Spring-Social